# IndexedDB on Mobile Safari using IndexedDBShim polyfill

Tags: indexeddb

Have any one had experience of running production projects that would use Indexed DB API in Safari on iOS devices using [polyfill](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/)?

What problems can be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but currently has some limitations,
Updating or deleting a cursor opened on a index doesn't work yet, but it will be working soon!
The issues with indexes being undefined is fixed a few minutes ago.
Some methods currently don't support IDBKeyRanges (like idbobjectstore.get and idbobjectstore.delete) but do work when passed a primitive value. Passing the primitive value also works in native indexedDB so in most cases you can use that.

We are using it in our project right now and it does work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, multiple keys in object stores don't work.
Check the onupgradeneeded event. Sometimes it's not thrown when you expect it.
objectStoreNames method is replaced by objectStoreNames._items.
And some more limitations/changes that I can't remember. Be sure to test your app again and again. It's not easy. Check the repository to get the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

yes we are on the analytical and feasibility test for indexeddb usage and we are facing problems like this
[Safari shows indexed column undefined on indexeddb polyfill. How to retrieve data using indexes in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629010/safari-shows-indexed-column-undefined-on-indexeddb-polyfill)

It will be difficult to use indexeddb without indexes and safari is not supporting index keys even when using polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

Try out my library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home. It supports all, I means anything you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

We are using IndexedDb and that polyfill on iOS, Android and Chrome. We had some problems in the past but we managed the solve almost all of them. The owner of the polyfill is not very active but he authored one of my colleagues as admin. Keep an eye on [his fork](https://github.com/DickvdBrink/IndexedDBShim), he will be merging some fixes soon. I even heard him talk about indexes the other day.

PS: The changes might be in the custom branch.